# Gazebo complains about default_robot_hw_sim in hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo complains about default_robot_hw_sim in hydro. BTW if I run the script that is mentioned it runs says successful but still get the same error.

```
[ INFO] [1383162826.470781248]: pluginlib WARNING: In file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control-2.3.3-0raring-20131021-0406/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS is deprecated, please use PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS instead. You can run the script 'plugin_macro_update' provided with pluginlib in your package source folder to automatically and recursively update legacy macros.  Base = base_class_type, Derived = derived_class_type
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96176/gazebo-complains-about-default_robot_hw_sim-in-hydro/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question was answered in gazebo forum. The message can be ignored.
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5119/gazebo-complains-about-default_robot_hw_sim/

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0